# how to fix: delta time delay executing too soon

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino, milliseconds

I have a function myDelay which provided a pointer for the last time and an interval returns true/false if the interval has elapsed, however this seems to be returning true *too fast*.

currently I am just taking the current micros() negating the last delay point and comparing if it more than the supplied interval.

please note that micros() is an arduino function which returns the microseconds elapsed since startup.

```
    static unsigned long buttonDelay = 0;
    static int screenIndex = 0;
    boolean myDelay(unsigned long *delay, long interval) {
        unsigned long end = micros();
        if (end - *delay >= interval) {
            *delay = end;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void loop()
    {
            static const long buttonDelayInterval = 20000 * 1000;
        if(myDelay(&buttonDelay, buttonDelayInterval)){
            if(screenIndex++ > MAX_SCREEN_INDEX) screenIndex = 0;
            Serial.println(screenIndex);
        }
    }
```

expected output is for the screenIndex to only be incremented approximately once every 20 seconds.

Comment: What is micros function?

Comment: micros() it seems it's part of the arduino library, it returns microseconds since startup. (edited OP)

Comment: How more often is often? I'd suspect micros function returns unprecise values or wraps around quickly. There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: it seems that micros() has a resolution of 4 microseconds and an overflow of aprox 70 minutes. the myDelay seems to be executing multiple times per second. the code shouldn't be overflowing in this instance as it has only been on for a matter of minutes.

Comment: How often is it incremented? "Too fast" is a little vague.

Comment: I remember having problems with deep_sleep because it woke up way to fast. Could you set up your arduino and just 2x Serial.println(stuff) with a 5min period in between to verify your clock?

Comment: @molbdnilo, i have no way to measure how fast it is, except the fact that the serial.print is running many many times per second and not once every aprox 20 seconds

Comment: @Narase I just checked it with a 1 minute interval and it  ran every 1 minute.

Comment: Is it too fast every time or just the first one? In later case it could be the setup() taking too long

Comment: @Narase it's too fast every time (the setup taking too long and causing it to increment immediately isn't an issue).

Comment: Check value of your constant. If your int size is 16 bit, then 20000 * 1000 will overflow into something really small. Try `(unsigned long long)20000 * 1000`.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski this fixed it (rather than unsigned long long) i just appended L to one of the values)